# Magento - Fatal Error after Login on Dashboard - Custom Extension

Tags: php, config, magento

After adding the following code to the config.xml of my custom extension:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
    <partnersystemhelper>
    <class>Pinto_PartnerSystem_Helper</class>
    </partnersystemhelper>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

And creating the following class in Helper/Data.php :

```
class Pinto_PartnerSystem_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    // functions
}
```

Every time I log in to the admin I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Partnersystemhelper1_Helper_Data' not found in /home/users/inoxvftp/inoxtaps.eu/webshop/app/Mage.php on line 546
```

I have tried deleting the cache in var/cache and when I looked at includes/config.php the two lines for the compiler where already commented out.

I can't see any tabs in the navigation or the dashboard anymore because of the error.

Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a line in your code like this `Mage::helper('partnersystemhelper1')`, or `$this->helper('partnersystemhelper1')`. Or there is a piece of xml that has this attribute:
`module="partnersystemhelper1"`.
Search for that in your code and remove the `1` from it.

Comment: Thank you - the problem was the latter. I took out the 1's in module="partnersystemhelper1" and then I deleted the cache in var/cache and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

look at the error message, it's trying to load `Mage_Partnersystemhelper1_Helper_Data`, with the number **1**. So, somewhere in your code you have:

```
Mage::helper('partnersystemhelper1');
```

find it and correct it